# 401 prompt on 3G, but not on Wi-Fi - XmlHttpRequest over SSL with Basic Authentication, hard-coded credentials

Tags: javascript, ajax, authentication, ssl, xmlhttprequest

I have an XmlHttpRequest that uses hard-coded credentials for Basic Authentication. The website (HTML/CSS/JavaScript) itself is already authenticated with client certificates, so I'd rather just use anonymous authentication when calling the web service, but it returns empty data sets with the HTTP 200/OK code. I also tried just using the same client certificates as the website, but it also returns empty data sets, despite the HTTP 200/OK code. When I set it up to use Basic Authentication, the full data sets are returned. So, it seems like I might be stuck using Basic. Here's the simple request:

```
var xmlhttp = new XMLHttpRequest();
xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://foo.bar.com:5443/WebServices/Web.svc', true, username, password);

var sr = '<Envelope>' + 
        '<Body>' + 
        '<Method>' + 
            '<parameterlist>' + 
                '<parameter>param_1</parameter>' + 
            '</parameterlist>' + 
        '</Method>' + 
    '</Body>' + 
    '</Envelope>';

xmlhttp.onreadystatechange = function () {
    if (xmlhttp.readyState == 4) {
         if (xmlhttp.status == 200) {
           //successful
         }
     }
};

xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('SOAPAction', '\"http://SOAPAction\"');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Content-Type', 'text/xml;charset=UTF-8');
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Cache-Control', 'no-cache');
xmlhttp.send(sr);
```

Since I have hard-coded the credentials in the XHR, I usually see the 401 in the logs, immediately followed by the properly credentialed request, resulting in the 200 status. There is no 401 challenge prompt, which is the way I would like it to work. For example (edited for readability):

```
#Fields: date time s-ip cs-method cs-uri-stem cs-uri-query s-port cs-username c-ip cs(User-Agent) sc-status sc-substatus sc-win32-status time-taken
2013-07-10 11:55:23 192.168.201.145 POST /WebService.svc - 5443 - IP_ADDRESS USER_AGENT 401 0 0 31
2013-07-10 11:55:24 192.168.201.145 POST /WebService.svc - 5443 USERNAME IP_ADDRESS USER_AGENT 200 0 0 296
```

However, when I am on a 3G connection, or perhaps when Wifi connection is slower, I always get the 401 challenge prompt. I'm not sure why it would be different over a slower connection. Ideally, the 401 prompt would never show up.

I understand that one way to get around this is to use a web service proxy, but I can not find any examples of how to implement a very simple one. I have never created a web service proxy, and if that's my only option, I could use some guidance for a very simple implementation.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm still not entirely sure why this was happening, but I was able to fix it with the method posted [here](http://coderseye.com/2007/how-to-do-http-basic-auth-in-ajax.html).

It just uses Base64.js to create a hash from the username and password, and passes that in an authorization header.

```
xmlhttp.setRequestHeader('Authorization', auth);
```

I removed the username and password from the .open():

```
xmlhttp.open('POST', 'https://foo.bar.com:5443/WebServices/Web.svc', true);
```

The server doesn't send any 401 challenges at all. It results directly in a 200 status, which means the data loads even faster.